# Cannot find how my jobs are bound to runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a pipeline set up on Gitlab, within which my project is built and unit tests are run every time I commit a change to "developer" git branch.

Recently I've updated versions of some libraries in the project and after that builds on CICD started to fail and says that node.js version should be updated.

As I undestand I need to somehow edit settings of a container in which builds are run.
We have our own gitlab instance. As I see from the settings there are group of shared runners, used from many projects.
How can I find out which of those runners are used for my project? in the Gitlab GUI I can see tags assigned to the shared runners, but I don't see any tags in my .gitlab-ci.yml

Gitlab version is 15.4.2-ee
self-managed

Comment: So when you create runners, you can specify if that runner can run jobs without tags (which is what your CI sounds like) or if the runner can only run jobs that matches its tags. if all of your shared runners are configured to run any jobs without tags then your job could run on any of them. Best practice is to always specify tags to ensure your job runs on a runner that you know is capable of running your job and has all the requirements it needs

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#runner-is-allowed-to-run-untagged-jobs

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, so there are no other ways to bind a job to a runner? just either using tags or it will just use all the runners? well I guess then in my case all the runners are used, although it's pretty strange because there are many different projects and many runners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its not tagged it will run on any runner which is configured to run untagged jobs. Not just on any runner. By default runners don't run untagged jobs.